# How to change the week start day as sunday for database in oracle for reporting purpose

Tags: sql, oracle

Have tried changing `NLS_TERRITORY` and `NLS_LANGUAGE` still database is showing Monday as starting week.

```
Alter session set nls_territory = 'America'

select TRUNC(sysdate, 'iw') AS iso_week_start_date,
       TRUNC(sysdate, 'iw') + 7 - 1/86400 AS iso_week_end_date
from dual;
  2    3
ISO_WEEK ISO_WEEK
--------- ---------
20-AUG-18 26-AUG-18
```

Here the ISO_WEEK_START_DATE should start from 19-AUG-2018 which is sunday

Comment: I don't think ISO weeks are affected by NLS settings.

Comment: [From Wikipedia's "ISO week date" page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date): "Weeks start with Monday." Why do you want a result called `iso_week_start_date` to show something that *isn't* actually the ISO-8601-defined start of the week?

Answer (score 5):

`TRUNC(sysdate, 'iw')` returns first day of week according to ISO-8601 which is always Monday. For local weeks use `TRUNC(sysdate, 'WW')` which depends on current user session `NLS_TERRITORY`